# Azure SNAT secondary IP addresses for outbound connectivity

Tags: azure

I have a VM with two IP addresses, but I cannot form outbound connectivity using the secondary IP address unless I assign a public IP.  I do not have to.  You can see below when I try to force an SSH connection from that secondary IP, I don't get a reply back.  I am not looking to have a static public IP assigned but I want to have it masqueraded via some address in Azure just like the primary does.

Am I missing some setting/restriction within Azure?

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:60:b7:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.2.4/24 brd 10.1.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.1.2.6/24 brd 10.1.2.255 scope global secondary eth0:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

unixhost:  **ssh -b 10.1.2.6 me@somesystem.com**
   27 12.895296671     10.1.2.6 → 1.1.1.1   TCP 76 46933 → 8765 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=4269275914 TSecr=0 WS=128
   28 13.897546759     10.1.2.6 → 1.1.1.1   TCP 76 [TCP Retransmission] 46933 → 8765 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=4269276917 TSecr=0 WS=128
   29 15.913542597     10.1.2.6 → 1.1.1.1   TCP 76 [TCP Retransmission] 46933 → 8765 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=4269278933 TSecr=0 WS=128
   30 20.169545427     10.1.2.6 → 1.1.1.1   TCP 76 [TCP Retransmission] 46933 → 8765 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=4269283189 TSecr=0 WS=128
   31 28.361550433     10.1.2.6 → 1.1.1.1   TCP 76 [TCP Retransmission] 46933 → 8765 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=4269291381 TSecr=0 WS=128
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect out side that masquerade your private IP via some address, you can use Azure Load Balance, set the NAT rule with your secondary IP, but it also need a public associated with the front end of Load Balance.

In Azure. if you want to connect the internet, you have to need a public. Load Balance just can help masquerade your private IP with NAT rule.

You can get more details about Azure Load Balance following this document [Fundamental Load Balancer features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview#fundamental-load-balancer-features).